# Hyundai Verna (Accent) handbrake light is on everytime

Tags: hyundai, handbrake, accent

My Hyundai Verna/Accent handbrake light comes on when driving and just off in shortly times

Any ideas to what might be causing this, if so what parts will need to be replaced/repaired?

Comment: Check your owners manual to determine if you have more than one brake warning light. It could be a parking brake or service brake issue

Answer (score 2):

The brake light in the dash can come on if your brake reservoir is below where it should be. Check this, but before you do, double check to see if you need brakes. If you just pour brake fluid into your reservoir and need your brake pads replaced, you'll make a mess as you'll have too much fluid in.

If you do need brake fluid, clean off the cap of the reservoir with a clean rag, take it off, and read what it says. It will probably say to use DOT3 brake fluid which can easily be found at most parts stores. Fill the reservoir up to the line which should be seen on the side.

If your reservoir is low and you don't need new brakes, you may have a leak somewhere. Check your calipers/wheel cylinders for any leakage.

If the reservoir is not low, some vehicles will indicate with the brake light being on if you have a tail light which is out.

Comment: Isnt it dot4 fluid? In the uk I find dot4 is standard and anything else will cause a search to be had.

Comment: In most cases, you can use either DOT 3 or 4, unless called for by the vehicle manufacturer. You can always step up to DOT 4 from DOT 3, but you don't want to do it the other way around. DOT 4 has a higher boiling point, is the main difference.